# Emacs Org-Mode List with TIKZ nodes exporting incorrectly to Xelatex Latex

Tags: list, export, org-mode, tikz, xelatex

How do I include Tikz Nodes inside of a list environment without the org-mode latex export breaking the environment?

I have some code, which create braces along several list items using Tikz. The list should ideally look like this (this is my manually typed xelatex code...and actually I would prefer "enumerate" but one thing at a time):

```
\begin{itemize}[noitemsep=nosep]
   \item who tells (to whom)?
     \tikz[remember picture] \node[coordinate,yshift=0.5em] (n1) {}; %max 2 sentences
   \item what happens?
   \item to whom?
   \item with what result?
     \tikz[remember picture] \node[coordinate] (n2) {};
     \tikz[remember picture] \node[coordinate, yshift=0.5em] (n3) {}; %max 4 sentences
   \item beginning
   \item how action rises
   \item climax
   \item denouncement
     \tikz[remember picture] \node[coordinate] (n4) {};
\end{itemize}
```

**The problem:** The breaks in the list for the Tikz code is causing a break in the list environment, so that I end up with multiple lists, when I only want one list.

**See org-mode code below:**

```
* My list starts here
 -  who tells (to whom)?
      #+BEGIN_LaTeX
      \tikz[remember picture]\node[coordinate,yshift=0.5em] (n1) {}; 
      #+END_LaTeX
 -  what happens?
 -  to whom?
 -  with what result?
     #+BEGIN_LaTeX
     \tikz[remember picture] \node[coordinate] (n2) {};\tikz[remember picture] \node[coordinate, yshift=0.5em] (n3) {}; 
     #+END_LaTeX
 -  beginning
 -  how action rises
 -  climax
 -  denouncement
     #+BEGIN_LaTeX
     \tikz[remember picture] \node[coordinate] (n4) {};
     #+END_LaTeX
```

**See Latex Output here:**

```
\begin{itemize}
\item who tells (to whom)?
\end{itemize} <--THIS IS THE PROBLEM, HOW CAN I STOP THE ITEMIZE ENVIRONMENT FROM ENDING HERE
\tikz[remember picture]\node[coordinate,yshift=0.5em] (n1) {}; 
\begin{itemize}
\item what happens?
\item to whom?
\item with what result?
\end{itemize}<--THIS IS THE PROBLEM AGAIN
\tikz[remember picture] \node[coordinate] (n2) {};\tikz[remember
picture] \node[coordinate, yshift=0.5em] (n3) {}; 
\begin{itemize}
\item beginning
\item how action rises
\item climax
\item denouncement
\end{itemize}<--THIS IS THE PROBLEM AGAIN, IT SHOULD BE THE ONLY \end{itemize} AND AT THE BOTTOM
\tikz[remember picture] \node[coordinate] (n4) {};
```

Comment: Which org-mode version? In Org-mode version 7.9.2 (release_7.9.2-466-g6e73c2), that is, recently obtained from git, I only obtain one list when exporting to LaTeX.

Comment: pressing M-x results in: org-mode version 6.33x. I am wondering how to upgrade org-mode inside Aquamacs. Thanks for your comment. I will try to upgrade org-mode. Should not be too difficult.

Comment: rvf0068, I just upgraded my org-mode to 7.9.2 and it is still not working. Please confirm your results.

Comment: Nevermind, apparently I just needed to indent the #+BEGIN_LaTeX
      \tikz[remember picture]\node[coordinate,yshift=0.5em] (n1) {}; 
      #+END_LaTeX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this problem is to indent the tikz code in the list. I only realized this after indenting the code on this website for readability, when I realized that that was the solution! I was testing the new version of org-mode, which rvf0068 suggested, when it occurred to me that the indentation is the solution.

```
-  who tells (to whom)?
   #+BEGIN_LaTeX
   \tikz[remember picture]\node[coordinate,yshift=0.5em] (n1) {}; 
   #+END_LaTeX
 -  what happens?
 -  to whom?
 -  with what result?
```

**NOT**

```
-  who tells (to whom)?
#+BEGIN_LaTeX
\tikz[remember picture]\node[coordinate,yshift=0.5em] (n1) {}; 
#+END_LaTeX
 -  what happens?
 -  to whom?
 -  with what result?
```